# When I print dynamically allocated arrays it prints only the last value

Tags: c

I try to make a program that will take a directory and it will save in a dynamically allocated array the path of the files whose is in the directory. I insert the paths but when I try to print the array the output is only the last path.  I am new in the dynamically allocated array so any advice will help me!!!

Below are the code and the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    


    char** arrayWithPaths; 

    int counter=0;

    int pathCounter=0;
         
    char *path= (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char*));

    
    //If the argv is equal with 1 then there is not a path
    //If the argv is equal with 2 then there is a path
    //If the argv is not equal with 1 neither with  2  then there is more than 1 path
    
    if (argc == 1 )
    {
        
    }else if (argc == 2){

        arrayWithPaths = calloc(50,sizeof(char*));
       
       
        DIR *dir = opendir(argv[1]);

        if (dir != NULL){

            struct dirent *dirP;


            while ((dirP = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
            {

                counter++; 

                if (counter > 2)
                {

                    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
                    char *lastLetter = argv[1]+len-1;
                    
                    if (*lastLetter != '/')
                    {
                        sprintf(path,"%s/%s", argv[1], dirP->d_name);
                        arrayWithPaths[pathCounter]=path;
                    }else{
                        sprintf(path,"%s%s", argv[1], dirP->d_name);
                        arrayWithPaths[pathCounter]=path;
                    }
                    
                    pathCounter++;

                }

               
            }

            
            
        
            
           for (int i = 0; i < pathCounter; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", i);
                printf("%s\n",arrayWithPaths[i]);
            }
            
            
            
        free(arrayWithPaths);


        closedir(dir);

        free(path);



        }else if (ENOENT == errno){

            printf("Directory does not exist\n");

        }

    }else{
        printf("Input only one path!");
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

The current output

```
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
```

The output that I want

```
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/2.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/3.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/4.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/5.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/emptyOne.txt
/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/lslab/text/nameOfSomething.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char path= (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
```

Okay, `path` is a pointer to a single block of memory that you allocated.

```
                    arrayWithPaths[pathCounter]=path;
```

Each time through the loop, you add the value of `path` to your array. But the value of `path` never changes, it always points to the same block of memory that you allocated before you entered the loop.

So, at the end, you go through the loop and print each entry in the array. But each entry in the array is the very same pointer to the very same block of memory you allocated at the beginning that now happens to contain the last thing you put in it.

You need to allocate a new block of memory on each iteration in the loop and you need to add a *different* value to the array each time.

One simple way to do this:

```
                    arrayWithPaths[pathCounter]=strdup(path);
```

The `strdup` function allocates a new chunk of memory each time and copies the string pointed to by `path` into it.

Comment: `strdup()` is POSIX, not standard C, so it may not be available on non-POSIX systems.  It's almost trivial to replicate, however, which is probably one reason why it's not standard C.